# Is supplication used correctly here?

Tags: word-usage

> Many people ask with supplication about which generation is happier?

Comment: It seems like an odd usage to me, but we would need the context of it to decide for sure.  Who would the people be supplicating to?

Comment: It almost surely cannot be correct, because it ends with a question mark, but does not appear to be able to function as a question...

Comment: Supplicants tend to want tangible things, not the mere opinion of others.

Answer (score 1):

Supplication requires a relationship.  A supplicant is one who asks reverently of another, the other being a great person / being than the asker.

You could also use the word, reverence, to get a feel for the proper use of supplication.

> Many people ask with reverence about which generation is happier.

In this context, who are they revering? Who would they supplicate to?  For instance, this could make sense:

> When they approach God, many people ask with supplication about which generation is happier.

Whereas this would not make sense:

> When people get together in the bar to talk about society, many people ask with supplication about which generation is happier.

** As a side note, you are making a statement so the sentence would end with a period. And it would flow more naturally like, "Many people ask which generation is happier."

Comment: Please use quote text rather than code blocks.